# My regex for oracle sql does not work

Tags: regex, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to `regexp_replace` function in oracle sql. Here is my sample strings in my table column.

```
CV35 0DB    AC
W2 4PL      AC
OX17 7HP    AC
DE55 4RF    AC
GU13 9PU    AC
W1D 7EG     AC
CR8 2NE     AC
```

I wanna extract the ones having a letter in the beginning and following a number. So according to my approach only

```
W2 4PL      AC
W1D 7EG     AC
```

must be retained. I should stress that the numbers existing in this string are also texts. That is they are not numbers. Here what i have tried:

```
select distinct aa.ny,regexp_replace(aa.ny,'^[A-Z]{1}[0-9]') from  wos_source.address aa where upper(nu)='ENGLAND';
```

According to this query it only returns:

```
72046       AP  72046       AP
```

It seems it takes everything no matter which character there exist...

Thank in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need REGEXP_LIKE in the where clause:

```
select distinct aa.ny from  wos_source.address aa
where REGEXP_LIKE (aa.ny, 'pattern')
and upper(nu)='ENGLAND';
```